# High Trust App Unable to launch in dev

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, sharepoint-addin, high-trust-app

I have a vm dev environment with SharePoint 2013 (SP1 +  October 15 CU) and a SQL server.  I have a User Profile Service Application, App and Subscription Setting Application and all the services are started.  I created a self-signed certificate in IIS and exported the PFX and CER for creating a new SPTrustedRootAuthority and new SPTrustedSecurityTokenIssuer.

I created a brand new TestApp (visual studio 2015 update 1, Office dev tools at same level) and tried launching it (verified cert path, password, and IssuerID).  I get to the page to trust the app which I select, but then I am redirected to AppRedirect.aspx and it spins for forever.  I inspected the page and found a hidden form with an error in one of the fields:

> "The Azure Access Control service is unavailable."

Only think in ULS (even with verbose logging enabled) is a similar message:

> Error when get token for app
>   i:0i.t|ms.sp.ext|a978d8ad-8b8e-4f37-a99e-eaa1af75d0e3@174e37d4-6011-4ab3-bfb3-7305b8cba8fe,
>   exception: Microsoft.SharePoint.SPException: The Azure Access Control
>   service is unavailable.
>
> App token requested from appredirect.aspx for site:  but there
>   was an error in generating it.  This may be a case when we do not need
>   a token or when the app principal was not properly set up.  Exception
>   Message:The Azure Access Control service is unavailable

I have been trying to set this up for a day and a half now and am stumped.  Even stranger, if I manually launch a page with the app redirect url provided in ULS, the app launches fine and I have an authenticated usable SharePoint context.  Any ideas on what is happening that prevents the app from launching?

Answer (score 2):

So I was never able to get the self signed certs working as described on technet, but [following these steps](http://www.appzinside.com/2015/03/13/configure-an-environment-to-run-your-provider-hosted-high-trust-apps-in-sharepoint-2013/), I was able to get everything running and it provide me a more realistic setup to prod/dev.  I think the error about Azure ACS is a misdirect, but it is still disappointing to not be able to get the "easy" way running based on technet articles.